# Why PHP $_SESSION variable not working when being used in header() method?

Tags: php, session, http-headers, session-variables, http-status-codes

Recently, I came across a weird contrast while developing a PHP script.
The point is, I want to send an HTTP response status code to another page using the global `$_SESSION` variable. Then on the destination page, I will send this HTTP response status code to the browser by using the `header()` method. It doesn't matter what the HTTP response status code is. For example we consider here *"422 Unprocessable Entity"*.
So, easily we write our script:

**file1.php:** (the source file)

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['xyz'] = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
header('Location: file2.php');
```

**file2.php:** (the destination file)

```
<?php
session_start();
header("HTTP/1.1 " . $_SESSION['xyz']);
var_dump($_SESSION['xyz']);
unset($_SESSION['xyz']);
```

After entering URL `example.com/file1.php`, we will be transferred to the destination (`example.com/file2.php`) without any problems. In the browser console (Network tab) we will see a 422 error. No error_log file has created and also the output content of the page is:

```
string(24) "422 Unprocessable Entity"
```

Everything looks good. **But the problem is**, if you use https://httpstatus.io/ to check the correctness of the header sent, in addition to creating an error_log file on your server, you will encounter the following output:

[image: wrong status code]
[image]

Which is quite confusing. Moreover, the content of error_log file is:

```
[02-May-2021 22:21:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "xyz" in /www_root/file2.php on line 3
[02-May-2021 22:21:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "xyz" in /www_root/file2.php on line 4
```

which means that the variable `$_SESSION['xyz']` has not set.

I tried to debug the script simply by modifying `file2.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
header("HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity");
var_dump($_SESSION['xyz']);
unset($_SESSION['xyz']);
```

Then, the problem was solved strangely:

[image]

Now I want to ask the question, is the basis of my method (passing HTTP response status code to another page) correct? If so, why do I get error? Does the `header()` method execute in PHP before receiving `$_SESSION` variables? What is the execution schedule of these two functions? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that something went wrong in the site checking.

Specifically, the behaviour you lament is the one I would expect if the server did follow the redirect, **but without setting the session cookie header**. If that is the case, then the `file2.php` got an empty session.

Try outputting the `session_id()` in file2.php and see whether it changes (it shouldn't, if the cookie is transferred correctly) between file1 and file2.

Or maybe send in the location a GET variable like id=(session id). Then in file2.php verify whether the id you got session_id() or not. If it is not, connect to the "good" session id (see session_id man page). And see if *then* you see the xyz key. Chances are that you will.

Comment: Your suspicion may be correct. I think there is no problem with our script at all. The problem is that 'httpstatus.io' does not hold on and transfer $_SESSION variables during the transition from file1.php to file2.php (302 Redirect). Now in this situation, what do you think is the simplest way to prevent error_log from being created?

Comment: Simply by add `if(isset($_SESSION['xyz']))` after `session_start()`, error_log will no longer created.